# Calling non-hosted Sonar using Travis Plugin

Tags: sonarqube, travis-ci, sonarqube-scan

I'm trying to push to self run SonarQube after Travis runs tests and am unable to do so with the official plugin.

Only work around I can get to work is pulling sonar scanner directly but I would rather be using the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Travis-CI plugin is designed specifically to work with SonarCloud. To analyze from Travis with another instance, you'll need to explicitly configure your built to execute analysis pointed at your self-hosted instance.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Do you know if the plugin exposes the raw sonar-scanner bin that I can use as opposed to fetching it explicitly?

Comment: I don't @GrahamMyers.